# MS Access - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT * FROM exclusivity
left join patent on (exclusivity.[Appl_Type]=patent.[Appl_Type] AND exclusivity.[Appl_No]=patent.[Appl_No] AND exclusivity.[Product_No]=patent.[Product_No])
left join products on (exclusivity.[Appl_Type]=products.[Appl_Type] AND exclusivity.[Appl_No]=products.[Appl_No] AND exclusivity.[Product_No]=products.[Product_No]);
```

The above query gives Syntax error

> (missing operator) in query expression 'exclusivity.[Appl_Type]=patent.[Appl_Type] AND exclusivity.[Appl_No]=patent.[Appl_No] AND exclusivity.[Product_No]=patent.[Product_No])
>   left join products on (exclusivity.[Appl_Type]=products.[Appl_Type] AND exclusivity.[Appl_No]=products.[Appl_No] AND exclusivity.[Product_No]=products.[Product_No]);'

What could be possible reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access has weird requirements for parentheses around joins:

```
SELECT *
FROM (exclusivity left join
      patent
      on exclusivity.[Appl_Type] = patent.[Appl_Type] AND
         exclusivity.[Appl_No] = patent.[Appl_No] AND
         exclusivity.[Product_No] = patent.[Product_No]
    ) left join
    products
    on exclusivity.[Appl_Type] = products.[Appl_Type] AND
       exclusivity.[Appl_No] = products.[Appl_No] AND
       exclusivity.[Product_No] = products.[Product_No];
```

Comment: As an addition - Here it is well explained which join types can be nested how: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/perform-joins-using-access-sql

Comment: This is one of the reasons I have raised the ticket: [Upgrade Access SQL dialect to current ANSI standards](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar). Please, readers, vote!